# slack interactive button give an error " chat.attachmentAction not ok: internal_error "

Tags: webhooks, slack

I am trying to implement slack in my project using Bot User OAuth Token. I am able to sent some button on a channel but in response i get a error

```
" chat.attachmentAction not ok: internal_error "
```

Interactivity is ON and also request URL  is also set.

I tried to solve this from documentation.

Comment: can u share more details or your code ?